# Игра на javascript. если ли способ вставить переменную в css? чтобы блоки на css и js скользили по линиям

Tags: javascript, html, css

Делаю игрушку на js возникла проблема. Блоки на css и они должны чередоваться, вопрос как поставить переменную в стиль чтобы генерировать блоки и с помощью функции setinterval проводить их по одной линии. Подскажите кто нибудь как сделать блоки для препятствий уникальными чтобы они не мигали и в css стиле прокатывали по линии с уникальным id или может есть еще какое нибудь решение на javascript? https://amir248.github.io/cockerel/ Всем заранее Большое спасибо! И как в сбербанке больше чем спасибо!

```
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Game cockerel</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
#line {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: flex;
}
#line1 {
width: 25%;
height: 100%;
background-color: rgb(201, 230, 185);
flex-flow: row;
}
#line2 {
width: 25%;
height: 100%;
background-color: rgb(201, 230, 185);
}
#line3 {
width: 25%;
height: 100%;
background-color: rgb(201, 230, 185);
flex-flow: row;
}
#line4 {
width: 25%;
height: 100%;
background-color: rgb(201, 230, 185);
}
#line5 {
width: 25%;
height: 100%;
background-color: rgb(201, 230, 185);
flex-flow: row;
}
#line6 {
width: 25%;
height: 100%;
background-color: rgb(201, 230, 185);
}
.pic_push_down {
display: block;
position: relative;
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
margin-left: 25%;
margin-Right: 50%;
top: 77%;
}
#side {
background-color: azure;
width: 70%;
}
button {
background-color: red;
border: 10px;
width: 50px;
height: 75px;
}
.info {
display: block;
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
margin-left: 50%;
margin-right: 50%;
top: 5%;
}
.hedge_stone1, .hedge_stone6, .hedge_stone2, .hedge_stone3, .hedge_stone4, .hedge_stone5 {
position: absolute;
margin-left: 5px;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
top: -50px;     
background-color: brown;
}
</style>

<body>
<div id="line">
<div id="line1">
<p class="pic_push_down" id='pic1'></p>
<p class="hedge_stone1"></p>
</div>
<div id="line2">
<p class="pic_push_down line2" id='pic2'></p>
<p class="hedge_stone2"></p>
</div>
<div id="line3">
<p class="pic_push_down" id='pic3'></p>
<p class='hedge_stone3'></p>
</div>
<div id="line4">
<p class="pic_push_down" id='pic4'></p>
<p class='hedge_stone4'></p>
</div>
<div id="line5">
<p class="pic_push_down" id='pic5'></p>
<p class='hedge_stone5'></p>
</div>
<div id="line6">
<p class="pic_push_down" id='pic6'></p>
<p class="hedge_stone6"></p>
</div>
<div id="side">
<div align="center">
<br>
<button onClick="left_button()">
<=</button> <button onClick="right_button()">=>
</button>
<br>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="info">тут инфо</div>
<style>
.alert {
padding: 15px;
border: 1px solid #d6e9c6;
border-radius: 4px;
color: #3c763d;
background-color: #dff0d8;
}
</style>
<script>
/* еще не понятно для чего это но может пригодиться. */
let div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = "alert";
div.innerHTML = "<strong>Всем привет!</strong> Вы прочитали важное сообщение.";
document.body.append(div);
</script>
<script>
/* нужно создать цсс стиль чтобы динамически генирировать новые блоки */
/*let style = document.createElement('rande_hedge_stone');
style.type= 'text/css';
style.innerHTML = '.cssClass { color: #F00; }';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
document.getElementById('someElementId').className = 'cssClass';*/
/* ----------------------------------------
Большой скрипт с препятствиями и временем
-------------------------------------------*/
for(y = 0; y <25; y++); // для будущего переменная в начале док
setInterval(randomBlock, 1000);
function randomBlock(){
/* if(stone.style.display = "none"){
stone.style.diplay = 'block';
} */ // это условие тут не работает но суть ясна! Его надо сделать.
let rand7 = Math.random().toFixed(1);
let number;
if(rand7<=0.2){
number = 6;
}else if(rand7>=0.2&&rand7<=0.3){
number = 5;
}else if(rand7>=0.4&&rand7<=0.5){
number = 4;
}else if(rand7>0.5&&rand7<=0.6){
number = 3;
}else if(rand7>0.6&&rand7<=0.8){
number = 2;
}else if(rand7>0.8){
number = 1;
}else{
console.log('что то пошло не так.');
}
console.log(rand7);
console.log(number);
let stone = document.querySelector('.hedge_stone'+[number]);
let distance_window = document.documentElement.clientHeight;/*Тут была какаето задумка, но сейчас это пустует.*/
let distance_stone =0;
function peremeshenie() {
stone.style.top = distance_stone;
if (distance_stone < window.innerHeight -50) { /* innerWidth - окно экрана в высоту*/
distance_stone = distance_stone + 1;
}
if(distance_stone>window.innerHeight-51){
stone.style.display ='none';
} 
}
setInterval(peremeshenie, 20); 
} 
// -----------------------------------
//-----переменные для управления-----
//-----------------------------------
var rightPressed = false;
var leftPressed = false;
var jumpPressed = false;
var upPressed = false;
var downPressed = false;
// ------------------------------------
/* скрипт тут ля управления перемещениями с клавиатура */
document.addEventListener('keydown', keyDownHangler, false);
function keyDownHangler(e) {
if (e.key == "f") {
right_button();
} else if (e.key == "s") {
left_button();
} else {
return;
}
}
if (keyDown = 'KeyF') {
right_button();
}
if (right_button) {
left_button();
}
document.onkeypress = function (event) {
console.log(event);
}
var i = 3;
var pic = document.getElementById('pic' + i).innerHTML = '<img id="cockerel.png" src="https://i.ibb.co/Gnk5Ln3/cockerel.png" alt="cockerel" border="0" width="50px">';

function left_button() {
if (i > 1) {
i = i - 1;
document.querySelector('#pic' + i).innerHTML = '<img id="cockerel.png" src="https://i.ibb.co/Gnk5Ln3/cockerel.png" alt="cockerel" border="0" width="50px">';
document.querySelector('#pic' + (i + 1)).innerHTML = ' ';
console.log(i);
} else if (i <= 1) {
return;
}
}
function right_button() {
if (i < 6) {
i++;
document.querySelector('#pic' + i).innerHTML = '<img id="cockerel.png" src="https://i.ibb.co/Gnk5Ln3/cockerel.png" alt="cockerel" border="0" width="50px">';
document.querySelector('#pic' + (i - 1)).innerHTML = '';
console.log(i);
}
else if (i >= 6) {
return;
}
}
</script>>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Какой-то поток сознания в вопросе, постарайтесь формулировать свои мысли так, чтобы они были понятны другим. И давать участок кода, который демонстрирует проблему и желаемое поведение, а не весь листинг с кучей посторонних функций.

Comment: вся проблема в том что нужно сделать стиль с уникальным ID или как то обозначать css блок, чтобы при .style.display = 'none' остальные блоки остались, нужен способ чтобы в css вставить переменную которая бы была аналогичной с js. Или какой нибудь другой способ чтобы поставить препятствие на пути. Задумка была при нажатии клавишу вверх ускорять setInterval как будто блоки надо обегать. Но блоки на одной линии начинают мигать. не понятно как решить эту проблему.

Comment: У стилей не может быть ID и проектировать приложение отталкиваясь от стилей является ошибкой. По крайней мере эти классы .hedge_stone{number} выглядят как попытка сделать приложение неправильно. Все манипуляции происходят исключительно в блоками HTML: помечать их, выбирать, устанавливать им стили и css-классы. Поэтому важно понимать, что сейчас есть и что вы вообще хотите получить в итоге.

Comment: Давайте по порядку, у вас есть некоторая игра в которой есть воображаемые вертикальные линии. По этим вертикальным линиям вниз падают блоки. Вы хотите, чтобы падающие блоки автоматически генерировались с течением времени. При этом на одной линии может быть несколько блоков. Я вас правильно понял?

Comment: Да все именно так. Вы правильно поняли. Даже не знаю кроме как css сделать блок который бы перемещался по "воображаемой вертикальной линии". т.к. блоки начинают мигать то нужно как то с генерировать уникальные блоки. Или какое либо другое решение со смыслом падающих блоков, или препятствий. Для игры думаю сделать скрипт на js с параметром clientHeight который если совпадет с персонажем(будет столкновение).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас сейчас происходит мигание, поскольку вы не создаете новый элемент, а берете старый и вешаете на него еще один таймер перемещения с другими координатами. Вот и выходит, что два таймера пытаются одновременно поставить блок в разные места, что порождает мигание. В принципе, достаточно было бы создать новый блок внутри `randomBlock()` и проблема бы исчезла.

Ну или лучше просто переделать так, чтобы блоки нормально создавались и не зависели от стилей.

```
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Game cockerel</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<style>
    * {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .flex {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
    }
    .row {
        width: 25%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: rgb(201, 230, 185);
        flex-flow: row;
    }
    .hedge_stone {
        position: absolute;
        margin-left: 5px;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        top: -50px;
        background-color: brown;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div class="flex">
        <div class="row"> </div>
        <div class="row"> </div>
        <div class="row"> </div>
        <div class="row"> </div>
        <div class="row"> </div>
        <div class="row"> </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        let interval = setInterval(() => {
            addBlock();
        }, 1000);

        function addBlock() {
            let line = document.getElementsByClassName("row")[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)];

            let block = document.createElement("p");
            block.classList.add("hedge_stone");
            line.appendChild(block);

            let distance_stone = 0;
            let interval = setInterval(peremeshenie, 20);

            function peremeshenie() {
                block.style.top = distance_stone;
                if (distance_stone < window.innerHeight - 50) { /* innerWidth - окно экрана в высоту*/
                    distance_stone = distance_stone + 1;
                }
                if (distance_stone > window.innerHeight - 51) {
                    block.style.display = 'none';
                    line.removeChild(block);
                    window.clearInterval(interval);
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```